# How to get the IP address from the nova list

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts

From Openstack, i need output like hostname, status and ip address only but i am getting hostname, status and id=ipaddress

```
    nova list | grep Hostname1 | awk '{print $4,$6,$12}'

    Output : 
         Hostname1   Active net1=10.192.1.22
```

I want only hostname, status and ip like below

```
  Expecting output 1 :
        Hostname1   Active   10.192.1.22

  Expecting output 2:
        Hostname1   Active  net1   10.192.1.22
        Hostname2   Active  net2   10.192.1.23
```

Advance thanks

Comment: Thats because the 12th field is `net1=10.192.1.22`. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `nova list`.

Comment: Are you looking for how to split $12 with `=` being the delimiter then?

Comment: yes.. i am looking that

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  I'm no scripting expert...

```
nova list | grep au-dev | awk '{ split($12, v, "="); print $4,$6,v[1],v[2]}'
```

Output

```
   bcollins@home:~/openstack$ nova list | grep au-dev | awk '{ split($12, v, "="); print $4,$6,v[1],v[2]}'
    au-dev ACTIVE bcollins_net 10.10.0.13,
```

Comment: au-dev is a hostname right..

Comment: I dont know the hostnames, i want to list the hostname, Network name, Status and IP address in that what to do

Comment: Can u explain above command how it works

Comment: If you simply remove ` | grep au-dev` it will list all of the instances.  As far as an explanation, AWK reads the output lines and splits them into variables based on number assignments.  Then my addition with `split` simply takes the last variable $12, and splits it into an array by using `=` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The new `openstack` cli commands have good options to do much of the filtering for you

```
openstack server list --help

List servers

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
...
  --name <name-regex>   Regular expression to match names
...
output formatters:
  output formatter options

  -f {csv,json,table,value,yaml}, --format {csv,json,table,value,yaml}
                        the output format, defaults to table
  -c COLUMN, --column COLUMN
                        specify the column(s) to include, can be repeated
```

So

```
openstack server list --name '.*webs.*' -f value -c Name -c Status -c Networks
```

But to get just the floating IP does still require some extra `awk` or similar:

```
openstack server list --name '.*webs.*' -f value -c Networks | awk '{print $2}'
```